# Can I use a custom connectionstring with Ui-O-Matic so my pocos are read from different database than Umbraco?

Tags: umbraco7

I want to keep all my umbraco tables in the default database, but access data in another database for use with UI-O-Matic. Can I specify a custom connectionstring for my UI-O-Matic pocos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Tim (author of UI-O-Matic) then yes:

https://our.umbraco.com/projects/developer-tools/ui-o-matic/computer-says-no/74427-external-database

You can put your own connectionstring in the web.config and then specify the name of it when "initializing" UI-O-Matic on a class:

```
[UIOMatic("Alias", "Display Name", "Item Name", ConnectionStringName = "YourConnectionName")]
```